# Frequency divisor in verilog

Tags: verilog, clock, frequency, circuit, digital-logic

i need a frequency divider in verilog, and i made the code below. It works, but i want to know if is the best solution, thanks!

```
module frquency_divider_by2 ( clk ,clk3 );
output clk3 ;
reg clk2, clk3 ;
input clk ;
wire clk ;
initial clk2 = 0;
initial clk3 = 0;
 always @ (posedge (clk)) begin
   clk2 <= ~clk2;
 end
 always @ (posedge (clk2)) begin
  clk3 <= ~clk3;
 end
endmodule
```

the circuit generated by quartus:

[image]

Comment: **One** `J-K flip flop` is [enough](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/bincount.html#c3) to create frequency divider (by 2). Your code is synthesized  **two** `D flip flops`, so it's not the best solution.

Comment: Are you asking if this is the best way to divide a clock, in logic, with verilog?  Or if this is the best way to get a clock running at 1/2 the speed of the original?  There many cases when you wouldn't want to use a clock generated by logic like this.

Comment: In verilog, what is best way to get a clock running at 1/2?

Comment: Do you mind telling me how to generate circuit from verilog code in quartus?

Answer (score 5):

Your block divides the frequency by 4 not 2. There is actually quite a good description of this on [Wikipedia Digital Dividers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_divider#Digital_dividers). Your code can be tidied up a bit but only 1 D-Type is required, which is smaller than a JK Flip-flop so is optimal.

```
module frquency_divider_by2(
  input      rst_n,
  input      clk_rx,
  output reg clk_tx
);

always @ (posedge clk_rx) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    clk_tx <= 1'b0;
  end
  else begin
    clk_tx <= ~clk_tx;
  end
end

endmodule
```

When chaining these types of clock dividers together be aware that there is a clk to q latency which is compounded every time you go through one of these dividers. IF this is not managed correctly by synthesis the clocks can not be considered synchronous.

Example on [EDAplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/39H), should open the waveform when run.

Comment: Thanks, I only need the frequency divided by 2!